# Difference between scalar SQL functions and aggregate SQL functions in SQLite

Tags: c++, sqlite

What is the exact difference between scalar SQL functions and aggregate SQL functions in SQLite?

I am getting a problem with the following code when attempting to create a new function in SQLite:

```
 int sqlite3_create_function(
     sqlite3 *db,
     const char *zFunctionName,
     int nArg,
     int eTextRep,
     void *pApp,
     void (*xFunc)(sqlite3_context*,int,sqlite3_value**),
     void (*xStep)(sqlite3_context*,int,sqlite3_value**),
     void (*xFinal)(sqlite3_context*)
 );
```

For a scalar SQL function, `xStep` and `xFinal` must be null, and for an aggregate SQL function, `xFunc` must be null.  I need to know which one to use and what the difference is.

Comment: I THINK YOU NEED TO YELL LOUDER I CANT HEAR YOU

Comment: Maybe if you turned off your caps lock, you'd get an answer.

Comment: **Step 1:** Accept some answers to your previous questions. **Step 2:** TURN OFF CAPS LOCK

Comment: @Bhargava: 9 Questions, 0 accepted answers & an All Caps question, pretty much summarizes everything.

Comment: Even if you convert this to lower case, it makes very little sense. I'd suggest you sit back, rethink the question, then rephrase it so others can understand it. BTW i removed the `linux` tag as this has nothing to do with Linux.

Comment: Come on, people.  The question is salvageable... did nobody else think to edit it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A [**scalar** function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ScalarFunction.html) is a function that operates on [scalar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(computing)) values -- that is, it takes one (or more) input values as arguments directly and returns a value.

An [**aggregate** function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) is a function that operates on [aggregate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aggregate) data -- that is, it takes a complete *set* of data as input and returns a value that is computed from all the values in the set.

By the way, these are the standard definitions of "scalar" and "aggregate" that you can find in any dictionary, and all these links are in the top five Google search results if you search for "scalar function" and "aggregate function".  [That's OK, we want StackOverflow to become the "definitive" answer for questions like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions), but in the interest of "teaching a man to fish" I feel compelled to remind you that you should do your own homework before asking other people to help answer your questions.